# Foursquare add tips with url parameter error

Tags: api, foursquare

Everytime I add a tip with url parameter (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/tips/add), I always get this error.

> {"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"bad tips/add request","requestId":"5703acdf498e8435008ddeea"},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{}}

Sample of the post request:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/add?text=Very+useful+tips!&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com&venueId=[VENUEID]&oauth_token=[TOKEN]&v=20131016
```

Comment: I am also facing the same above issue... ,  did you find any solution or Cause of this error?

Comment: Nope, we ended up not adding the url parameter.